# Replacing IEnumerable with List

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I have a basic doubt but I am not able to figure out myself.
I have a piece of code as follows:

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
            List.Add("A");
            List.Add("B");
            List.Add("sam);
            List.Add("Sed");

IEnumerable<string> names = from n in List where (n.StartsWith("S")) select n;
```

Why does the above code asks for a explicit conversion if IEnumerable is replaced with concrete implementation i.e., List.

i.e., if I use :

```
List<string> names = from n in List where (n.StartsWith("S")) select n;
```

has a compiler error.

I could blindly use Ienumerable , but I want learn what is happening when I use List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. This means that *every* list is an enumerable. But the relation does not work the way around. `IEnumerable<T>` *does not* implement `IList<T>`. There are many enumerables that are not a list; `Stack<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, arrays, `Dictionary<T, K>`, iterator blocks, etc.

You therefore have to explicitly create a list from the enumerable using the `ToList()` extensión method:

```
List<string> names = (from n in List where (n.StartsWith("S")) select n).ToList();
```

Comment: Just have a question, when I doing the operation on List<string> List = new List<string>();(In this case Name check)
, does the linq operation output will be in Ienumerable always? The input is List<string>

Comment: @user2630764 The ling extension methods will return an `IEnumerable<T>` independently of whatever `IEnumerable<T>` your are querying;  it can be a list, an array, an enumerable, etc., it wont matter. Furthermore, its important you know that linq is *lazy*. Which means the answer to your query will not be enumerated until you actually enumerate it (i.e. using a `foreach` statement or `ToList()`).

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit cast from `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`, since `IEnumerable` is simply not a `List`.

If you want to convert your enumerable to list, use `.ToList<T>()`:

```
List<string> names = (from n in List where (n.StartsWith("S")) select n).ToList();
```

Actually, your collection is even not enumerated until you call `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

List is IEnumerable, IEnumerable is not List

In theory, in case of linq your expression is err an expression, not a collection. Collection usually has a finite number of elements whereas expression is just a function to select elements from some collection by specified rules.

By writing

```
var expression = from n in orig_collection select n;
```

you define an expression(IEnumerable) describing rules that will be applied on enumeration of orig_collection

By writing

```
var collection = expression.ToList();
```

you enumerate through orig_collection to the end applying expression in process. That will result with a new List